# Can the volume change when I plug in headphones?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, headphones

I want the volume to change when I plug in headphones, because my netbook's speakers are really quiet but the earbuds I have are really loud when I plug them in.
I'm running Ubuntu Lucid Netbook Edition on an Asus eeePC 1005HA, if that's important.

Comment: hmmm, this is an interesting problem.  My first line of attack would be to see if there is a file in /sys or /proc that changes when you plug in headphones, and then monitor that.  Or you could bind a volume-lowering script to a hotkey and run it whenever you plug in your headphones.

Comment: +1. If someone knows for Windows, too, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Robert, it's built in to Windows 7 automatically. Windows remembers the volume level for when you have an external device plugged in and when you don't separately, so plug in your headphones, and tada, there you are.

Comment: @nhinkle: No, not every set-up has that behavior. Some just rewire the output just by hardware and still show Speakers in the OS...

Comment: Interesting. Does that depend on the manufacturer's drivers then or what? Have you actually seen a system running windows 7 where the behavior I described doesn't happen? All the ones I've seen have done it.

Comment: @nhinkle -- Using Win7. If I plug in my USB speakers, the volume changes, but if I attach or detach my 3.5mm headphones, there's no indication in the computer. Probably a hardware limitation, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is why headphones is often its own separate volume control from Front.  As far as I know, the only way to make speakers and headphones use different volume levels is to simply set the volume controls that way.  Have a look at the full mixer instead of just the single slider shown in the notification area.  I think you can reach a mixer from that slider, but if not:

```
alsamixer
```

Comment: Not quite exactly what I wanted, but the end result's the same.